# Why this sample works?

Tags: c++, stl, functor

```
  typedef pair<double, double> dd; 

  const double epsilon = 1e-6;

  struct sort_by_polar_angle { 
    dd center; 
    // Constuctor of any type 
    // Just find and store the center 
    template<typename T> sort_by_polar_angle(T b, T e) { 
        int count = 0;
        center = dd(0,0); 
        while(b != e) { 
                    center.first += b->first;
                    center.second += b->second;
               b++; 
            count++;
        } 
               double k = count ? (1.0/count) : 0;
        center.first *= k;
               center.second *= k;
   } 
   // Compare two points, return true if the first one is earlier 
   // than the second one looking by polar angle 
   // Remember, that when writing comparator, you should 
   // override not ‘operator <’ but ‘operator ()’ 
   bool operator () (const dd& a, const dd& b) const { 
        double p1 = atan2(a.second-center.second, a.first-center.first); 
        double p2 = atan2(b.second-center.second, b.first-center.first); 
        return p1 + epsilon < p2; 
   } 
  }; 

// ... 

vector < dd >  points; 

sort(all(points), sort_by_polar_angle(all(points)));
```

When sort_by_polar_angle() is called, is it function as a construnctor?
How the overloaded operator () correctly used?

Comment: what is all(), the sort_by_polar_angle is a constructor but not the one you've shown as they have different numbers of arguments.

Comment: It's wrong, too. You should definitely not have an epsilon in the ordering. if a==b and a==c then b==c.

Comment: Although it's clearly ugly, i am pretty sure all(C) has to be defined as a #define for "C.begin(), C.end()"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `sort_by_polar_angle()` in the `sort()` function, you are creating a temporary object of type `sort_by_polar_angle` (i.e. its constructor is called). Inside the sort algorithm, the functor object you passed is used something like `functor()` which will be translated into `functor.operator()`.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work for points on a straight line from the center.  The 'angle' of these is equal, so their order isn't determined.  Sorting these points will return undetermined results.

That's because  any "sort" operation should be 'strict': if a < b, then b > a.  (actually the [definition](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) is somewhat more complicated.)

```
dd a0 = { 0, 1 };
dd b0 = { 0, 2 };

assert( sort_by_polar_angle ()( a0, b0 ) && ! sort_by_polar_angle () ( b0, a0 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/functor.html) for a basic introduction to what functors are, or [google for c++ functor](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+functor).